# Replace # keyword from to the strings from the specified <div></div> using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem to replace keyword from input string

I have

```
<div id="Wrap">
<span class="common"><div id="main0"> to test it #sky </div></span>
</div>
```

I want to like this :

```
<div id="Wrap">
<span class="common">
<div id="main0"> to test <a href="http://mysite.com/search?q=#sky">#sky</a>  </div>
</span>
</div>
```

I tried with replace in jquery but not getting ...
I finding solution in jquery or javascript 
Please help me...

Comment: U should mark this question as answered one, there is an arrow mark in the left side of each answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$('#main0').html($('#main0').html().replace(/(#\w+)/g, '<a href="http://mysite.com/search?q=$1">$1</a>'));
```

Use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (which is just a normal JS function btw) with a regular expression, that matches `#` and word characters. `$1` is a backreference to the content of the first capture group `()`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/rYbJT/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it quick and easy with some caveats...

```
$('#element').html(function(i, html) {
   return html.replace(/#\w+/g, '<a href="http://mysite.com/search?q=$&">$&</a>';
});
```

This isn't the best way to do it as it may mangle things such as `title` attributes.

The more robust and guaranteed to only operate on text nodes...

```
var searchText = function(parentNode, regex, callback) {

   var node = parentNode.firstChild;

   do {

       if (node.nodeType == 1) {

           var tag = node.tagName.toLowerCase();

           if (tag == 'script' || tag == 'style') {
               continue;
           }

           searchText.call(this, node, regex, callback);

       } else if (node.nodeType == 3) {
           while (true) {

               // Does this node have a match? If not, break and return. 
               if ( ! regex.test(node.data)) {
                   break;
               } 

               node.data.replace(regex, function(match) {

                   var args = $.makeArray(arguments),
                       offset = args[args.length - 2],
                       newTextNode = node.splitText(offset);

                   callback.apply(window, [node].concat(args));
                   newTextNode.data = newTextNode.data.substr(match.length);
                   node = newTextNode;

               });
           }
       }
   } while (node = node.nextSibling);
}

searchText($('#element')[0], /#\w+/, function(node, match) {
    var link = $('<a />')[0];
    link.href = 'http://mysite.com/search?q=' + match.substr(1);                                    
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match));
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(link, node.nextSibling);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your use the `/g` switch on your expression, e.g.:

```
var match = /(#\w+)/g;
var text = $("#main0").text();
var result = text.replace(match, "<a href=\"http://mysite.com/search?q=$1\">$1</a>");

$("#main0").text(result);
```

The `/g` switch ensures it replaces all matches, not just the first instance.